# std::tuple, automatic constructor order

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Consider the following code snippet

```
struct MachineGun {
    explicit  MachineGun (int a);
};

struct Turret {
    explicit  Turret (char b);
};

struct Cannon {
    explicit  Cannon (std::string c);
};


template<typename... Ts>
struct Enemy {
    template<typename...Args>
    Enemy(Args&&... args)
        : device_list {std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {

    }

private:
    std::tuple<Ts...> device_list;
};
```

In the above constructor `std::forward` with the args unpack matches the correct constructor of the type inside the tuple but I cannot figure out how to try to make this match regardless of order of the types or parameters.

Hypothetically the code below represent the same thing: "Give me an enemy with a machinegun, turret and cannon"

```
Enemy<MachineGun,Turret,Cannon> e1(1,'1',std::string("1"));
Enemy<MachineGun,Turret,Cannon> e2("3",14,'5');
Enemy<Turret,MachineGun,Cannon> e3(std::string("14"), 5, '33');
```

But how do I actually enable this? `e1` will compile as the args list matches the type list order, both `e2` and `e3` should represent the same thing but how do I make my compiler understand this?

Comment: I realize this might be an XY problem, in the interest of learning I want to know how this can be done.

Comment: This can be done, but it seems like a bad idea.  It is a lot of work for negative benefit.  It is now harder to work out what that object is, and there are going to be corner cases you cannot automatically solve in a way that is reasonable to people writing code.  One way you'd do it is you'd ask if (args...) can be applied to (f) in any permutation and get the permutation, and then have a "permute args..." and a C++17 style "std apply".  This ends up requiring factorial compile time and a whole pile of code.

Comment: So to understand your question, you want your constructor to work regardless of if the argument order matches the tuple object order? That doesn't seem like a good idea, because the second that two of your classes take the same argument type it would be ambiguous which to use for which object.

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes, and I am also aware of that, there would also be an issue if/when some of the types take multiple arguments to the constructor.

Comment: Do you require a C++11 solution? Or a C++14 solution can be acceptable?

Comment: This is for a hobby project so c++14 works fine.

Comment: @arynaq C++17? If you don't need a specific version, don't specify one please :)

Comment: Other question: do you accept a solution where the argument type is required to be **exactly** the type of the constructor or you need a more flexible solution? I mean: if you require the exact types, `Enemy<MachineGun,Turret,Cannon> e2("3",14,'5');` can't be accepted, because `"3"` is a `char const [2]`, not a `std::string`. But if you want a more flexible solution, there is the problem that with a `char` you can initialize both `MachineGun` and `Turret` and the same with an `int`.

Comment: Implicit conversion is fine max :)

Comment: yes, is fine; but how do you think we can decide that `'5'` is used to initialize the `Turret` and `14` to initialize the `MachineGun`?

Comment: @Yakk: Unless OP wants to impose some kind of ordering on the types, in which case it's still a lot of work for negative benefit, but not factorial to compile

Comment: @AndyG In the limit it is factorial (to check that no ordering works) I think.  Even if it was like "typeA is preferred over typeB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem that I see in your question is the risk that the same value can initialize two different object in your tuple.

By example, given

```
Enemy<MachineGun,Turret,Cannon> e2("3",14,'5');
```

the integer (`14`) can initialize both `MachineGun` (a `int` constructor) and `Turret` (a `char` constructor and implicit conversion from `int` to `char`).

Same problem for `'5'`: can initialize both `MachineGun` (a `int` constructor and implicit conversion from `char` to `int`) and `Turret` (a `char` constructor).

The only way I see to solve this problem is to avoid constructor collisions adding deleted constructors.

So you can add a deleted `char` constructor for `MachineGun`

```
struct MachineGun
 {
   explicit MachineGun (int i)
    { /* something */ }

   MachineGun (char) = delete;
 };
```

and a deleted `int` constructor for `Turret`

```
struct Turret
 {
   explicit Turret (char c) 
    { /* something */ }

   Turret (int) = delete;
 };
```

More generally speaking, you have to add all deleted constructor necessary to avoid all possible ambiguities and to enable only one constructor for every argument you pass to `Enemy` constructor.

Anyway, given this simplification, you can write a couple of SFINAE alternative functions to select the right element, from a list, to construct an object

```
template <typename T, typename A0, typename ... As>
std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_constructible<T, A0>::value, T>
    selectArg (A0 && a0, As ...)
 { return T{ std::forward<A0>(a0) }; }

template <typename T, typename A0, typename ... As>
std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_constructible<T, A0>::value, T>
    selectArg (A0, As && ... as)
 { return selectArg<T>(std::forward<As>(as)...); }
```

And `Enemy` simply become

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Enemy
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<Ts...> device_list;

   public:
      template <typename ... Args>
      Enemy (Args ... args)
        : device_list { selectArg<Ts>(args...)... }
       { }
 };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct MachineGun
 {
   explicit MachineGun (int i)
    { std::cout << "- MachineGun: " << i << std::endl; }

   MachineGun (char) = delete;
 };

struct Turret
 {
   explicit Turret (char c) 
    { std::cout << "- Turret: " << c << std::endl; }

   Turret (int) = delete;
 };

struct Cannon
 {
   explicit Cannon (std::string const & s)
    { std::cout << "- Cannon: " << s << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename T, typename A0, typename ... As>
std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_constructible<T, A0>::value, T>
    selectArg (A0 && a0, As ...)
 { return T{ std::forward<A0>(a0) }; }

template <typename T, typename A0, typename ... As>
std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_constructible<T, A0>::value, T>
    selectArg (A0, As && ... as)
 { return selectArg<T>(std::forward<As>(as)...); }

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Enemy
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<Ts...> device_list;

   public:
      template <typename ... Args>
      Enemy (Args ... args)
        : device_list { selectArg<Ts>(args...)... }
       { }
 };

int main()
 {
   Enemy<MachineGun,Turret,Cannon> e1(1,'2',std::string("3"));
   Enemy<MachineGun,Turret,Cannon> e2("3",14,'5');
   Enemy<Turret,MachineGun,Cannon> e3(std::string("14"), 5, '3');
 }
```

Using `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<...>` the solution works also with C++11.

Comment: Thank you max! This is very helpful in understanding SFINAE which is still somewhat magic to me :)